# QGIS Align Rasters how to retain pixel values?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-2.14

I am attempting to align and then merge a number of rasters of the same resolution and extent, but where the pixels are slightly misaligned (creating small gaps when merged). This works fine using the Align Rasters tool, except that the pixel values are not retained and instead given a value of something like -3.23879e+8. I mostly want to keep the nodata pixels. Is this possible?

Comment: To clarify what's going on here (I think I have the same problem) - the Align Rasters tool seems to take no notice of the designated NODATA value. So if I have NODATA=-99999, those cells are considered to have a value of -99999; so if I use something other than nearest neighbour for resampling, I'll end up with a smooth transition from -99999 to the actual data - which is awkward.