# Aligning environmental layers causing a change in nodata values

Tags: qgis, alignment

I'm trying to align and re-sample environmental layers in QGIS (2.18.3). The layers I am using were obtained from the world clim data base Bio3,Bio18,Bio12,Bio10 as well as a Sheep and Cattle layer obtained from the FAO website. The World clim layers are at pixel size of 0.0416667,-0.0416667 and the two livestock layers are at a pixel size of 0.05,-0.05. Using the identify tool in QGIS I can see the ocean areas in this raster have a value of 0 for the livestock layers and a nodata value in the environmental layers (note my analysis is only interested on the land). I have been trying to use the raster align tool in QGIS so I can match these layers for some later Maxent analysis. I have used the following procedure in QGIS. Raster>Align Raster. Then I have been adding all the 6 layers, making the livestock layer the reference layers as it is of lower resolution. Checking the CRS value is at WGS 85, as well as adding coordinates to trim. This process occurs correctly, with pixel size matched. However my concern arises when I look at the trim and aligned rasters. Three raster Bio 10,12,18 all get a minimum value of -32768, were as Bio3 gets 43. When I used the identify tool again on the rasters Bio10,12,18 in the oceans show a value of -32768, whereas Bio3 give a value of 255 and the livestock layers are at 0.

Should the min and max values be matching in these layers if I am to compare between them?

Or are these values just proportional?

[image: This is the differences I get in the min and max after align trim]

[image: This is the Align raster option setup]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. You have written one very dense piece of prose.  Can you please **edit** it to contain screenshots to augment your explanation graphically?

Comment: Possibly related: [QGIS Align Rasters how to retain pixel values?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211114/qgis-align-rasters-how-to-retain-pixel-values)